Doble router-outlet en angular en distintas páginas
Estoy montando una app y he hecho un primer router-outlet en app.component.html para mostrar el juego de login/registro y lo uso para navegar entre estas dos pantallas. El típico enlace de "¿aún no estás registrado? pulsa aquí"
La cosa es que una vez que ese login lleve a la pantalla principal de mi app esta debería de tener otro router-outlet que no está funcionando.
El html es tal que así:
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

La idea sería que ese header maneje las rutas. Pero no está funcionando. Este es mi app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './views/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './views/profile/profile.component';
import { CampainsComponent } from './views/campains/campains.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './views/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'main', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: 'campains', component: CampainsComponent },
  ]  

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

He probado usar la propiedad

outlet

de Router pero nada, pongo un ejemplo:
<router-outlet name="aux">
{path: '/auxRouter', component: secondComponentComponent, outlet: 'aux'}


Para que funcione el segundo router-outlet las rutas deben estar dentro de children.

Lo he probado @Lobos pero tampoco a funcionado, a ver si vuelvo a cambiarlo con los children y actualizo la pregunta.

No entiendo bien, quieres que tener un <router-outlet /> y que despues (por ejemplo) dashboard tenga su propio router y profile otro router? Si es asi lo que tienes que hacer (no se si exista otra forma) es crear un modulo para cada "grupo de paginas" es decir, el modulo de auth tiene login y register, el modulo de dashboard tiene main, etc. y digamos, el modulo de admin tiene donde se gestiona todo.

Quizás no me he explicado bien @René Quiero un router-outlet que maneje el pase de pantallas entre login y registro. Pero luego, una vez logueas en la aplicación sea otro router outlet el que maneje el paso entre pantallas, profile, dashboard, lo que sea.
más que nada porque no veo forma de hacerlo todo en un solo router outlet.

Es lo que estaba diciendo, creas un modulo con su respectivo routing module y cargas cada modulo en lugar del componente, es la forma mas sencilla de hacer eso.

Para tener varios router-outlet lo que puedes hacer es tener varios módulos y cargarlos (no se si exista otra forma)
AppRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./admin/admin.module').then((m) => m.AdminModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

Agrego un solo "subrouting" de ejemplo:
AuthRoutingModule
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterPageComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'login',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}

Mientras que en el AuthModule
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthLayoutComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    RegisterPageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AuthRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}

En AuthLayout solamente tengo un <router-outlet /> para mostrar lo del router de Auth, y así con cada uno. No tienes que importar los modulos al AppModule porque se cargan mediante lazy load con loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule)

Gracias, me he pegado un poco con los modulos que ya tenía y demás para hacerlo funcionar, pero ya tira perfectamente.
